# String object is not callable when creating a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe in pandas as follows:

```
cols = ['col1','col2']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Does anybody know the solution here?

Comment: You have in your code something like `pd.DataFrame = 'a string'`. Now `pd.DataFrame` references a string. Try `print(pd.DataFrame)`. What is the output?

Comment: The code you've copied is running fine on my computer. Are you sure you haven't more code in your real world data that could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you've overwritten the value for `pd.DataFrame` by assigning it a string value. Find and remove the offending line, restart your kernel, and try again.